# Is there any method to provide the user an option to resize his image before uploading it to my tkinter fyi window

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library, crop

I am working on a project (tkinter-python) similar to the profile page of Instagram and have provided a function to the user to choose his image that needs to be uploaded to the window but I want a the size of the image that is going to be uploaded should be less than a specific size . What should I do to provide the option to the user to resize his image before uploading ?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import tkinter.messagebox as tmsg
#Profile Photo
image=Image.open(f"{name}.jpg")
width,height=image.size
area=width*height
if area<=160012:
  photo=ImageTk.Photoimage(image)
  Label(image=photo).place(X=1000,y=2)
else:
  tmsg.showinfo('Crop image','WIDTH X HEIGHT must be smaller than 160012')
```

Comment: tkinter GUI window and not tkinter fyi window

Comment: Why don't you resize the image for the user instead?

Comment: @acw1668 how to do that

Comment: As in your code, check whether area is greater than the allowed area, if yes, resize the image so that its area is less than the allowed area.  Then assign the image to the label.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the image resize for the user:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

MAX_AREA = 160012

#Profile Photo
name = 'path/to/user/profile/image'
image = Image.open(f"{name}.jpg")
width, height = image.size
area = width * height

if area > MAX_AREA:
    # determine the resize ratio
    ratio = (MAX_AREA / area) ** 0.5
    # calculate the resized width and height
    new_w = int(width * ratio)
    new_h = int(height * ratio)
    # resize the image
    image = image.resize((new_w, new_h))
    print(f'Image is resized from {width}x{height} ({area}) to {new_w}x{new_h} ({new_w*new_h})')

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1000x600')
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
Label(image=photo).place(x=1000, y=0, anchor='ne')
root.mainloop()
```